# The method flatMap() in the type Mono<Map<String,String>> is not applicable for the arguments ((<no-type> entry) -> {})

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a method which returns a Mono of Map as follows:

```
    private Mono<Map<String,String>> allLocs(){
        return all().collectList()
                .flatMap(list -> {
            Map<String, String> allData = new HashMap<String, String>();
            if (list.size() > 0) {
                list.forEach(entry -> {
                    if(entry.getCountryCode()!=null)
                    allData.put(entry.getCountryCode(), entry.getCountryName());
                });
            }
            return Mono.just(allData);
        });
    }
```

When I'm trying to use this map in an external method, I'm getting below error in line 1 of generateComplianceResponse method

```
Error:
The method flatMap() in the type Mono<Map<String,String>> is not applicable for the arguments ((<no-type> entry) -> {})

Code:
private void generateComplianceResponse(Compliance compliance){
        allLocs().flatMap(entry-> {
        complianceResponse.setCountry(entry.get(complianceResponse.getCompliancePort().substring(0,3)));
        });
}
}
```

Comment: as an aside, the code in `generateComplianceResponse` will never be executed as you can never subscribe to that `Mono` as it is not returned. "Nothing happens until you subscribe"

Comment: I did not understand what exactly you are trying to say, could you please explain with an example as to what exactly I am missing